# In Django, when I call User.objects.create_user(username, email, password) - why does post_save get called twice?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-errors

In views.py I have the following view which gets called when a new user account is registered.  All it does is get the username, email, and password from the request, then try to create a user with those credentials.  In the code below, "A" gets printed, but "B" does not, because it crashes:

```
views.py

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query_dict = request.POST
        username = query_dict['username']
        email = query_dict['user_email']
        password = query_dict['password']
        role = query_dict['role']
        print "A"
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        # the handler is called here and creates the user profile
        print "B"
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        user_profile = user.get_profile()
        user_profile.role = role
        user_profile.save()
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

In `myapp/models.py` I have the following code for the handler.

```
'models.py`

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "created="+str(created)
    if created: # as opposed to being saved after being created earlier, I assume
        print "attempting to create a user profile for "+instance.username
        up = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        print "created a new UserProfile: <"+str(up)+">"
```

When I run my app, the print output is:

```
A
created=True
attempting to create a user profile for john
created a new UserProfile: <john - >
created=True
attempting to create a user profile for john
~~~~CRASHES~~~~
```

I have noticed throughout my development over the last couple of days that the `create_user_profile` method gets called twice when I run `User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)`  I copied the handler code directly out of the docs, so I'm pretty sure it correct (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).  I don't know exactly where in the django code the `create_user_profile` method gets called from, but I am assuming that it sets the `created` flag to true only if the save method that invoked the handler was due to an object being created.  Over the last couple of days this code has been working correctly, but all of a sudden today the second time the `create_user_profile` method gets called by the handler, the `created` flag is set to true, just like it was the first time.  This is causing my app to crash with an `IntegrityError`, complaining that it can't create two objects with the same primary key.

So there are two things I don't understand.  First: why does post_save happen twice when I only called `User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)` once; second: why did the `created` flag all of a sudden stop working like expected?

How can I debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible that your models.py file is being imported, and run, twice. In this case, the same signal handler would be attached twice, and would fire twice when a model instance is saved.

This can easily happen if you import it once as

```
import myapp.models
```

and again as

```
import myproject.myapp.models
```

Printing something to the console at the top of the file might give you an idea whether that is what is happening or not.

Regardless, you can prevent a signal handler from being registered multiple times by giving it a unique `dispatch_uid`. Django will check on `Signal.connect` to see if a handler has already been registered for the same sender with the same UID, and will not re-register it if it has.

Change your signal connecting code to something like

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid='create_user_profile')
```

and see if that helps

Comment: Wow, thanks.  It turns out models.py was being imported twice.  Without StackOverflow I don't think I could have debugged that given the rest of the week.  Your UID trick also worked.

Comment: I can't figure out how models.py is being imported twice, though.  Can I add code to the print statement at the top of the file which lets me know who or how it is being imported?  Right now it appears to be imported the first time as soon as I start runserver, it gets imported a second time as soon as I start to do anything with my app.

Comment: Oops, I appear to have spoken too soon.  Looking carefully at my print output I see that my app started working again, which made me think that your solution worked, but even though I set the `dispatch_uid` as you recommended, the `create_user_profile` method is still being called twice.  This time the `created` flag is false the second time around, which is why things are working again.  I'm afraid I have some sort of race condition, however, and there is no telling when the flag might go back to true on the second call.  So, even though I set the `dispatch_uid`, the method is called twice.

Comment: I believe that the second time, your signal is being called by the `update_last_login` method. This is triggered by the `login(request, user)` call, and it *also* calls `User.save()`. This time, though, the user isn't new, so `created` is `False`. Everything is working as it should, and that's why you test for created in your signal handler.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  It was always being called twice, but they were not always the same two calls.  Your UID method does work because when I remove the UID the method is called twice before printing "B", due to the method being registered twice, but when I put the UID in the second method call happens after the "B" is printed.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is happening to me, I really appreciate this answer!